# Как объявить переменную приватного вложенного класса

Tags: java

Вот пример:

```
public class A {
    private class B {}
}

public class C {
    // B b; ?
}
```

Объект, вообще говоря, создавать не нужно, а нужна именно переменная этого типа.

Answer (score 1):

Класс `B` имеет область видимости только внутри класса `A`, поэтому влиять на `B` можно только методами `A`.
P.S Если уберете `private` с класса `B`, то сможете к нему обратиться через такую конструкцию `A.B`.

Comment: Естественно. 
Я имел ввиду применение методов, к примеру 
`// A.getInnerClass.getClass b`
т.е. если возможно, через методы передать тип класса и объявить переменную.

Класс `B` должен оставаться `private`

Comment: Если класс будет приватным, то он будет виден только внутри родительского класса и получить его экземпляр у вас не выйдет.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите скрыть какую-то реализацию во внутреннем классе, но иметь возможность ссылаться на неё через поля и переменные - добавьте в вашу иерархию интерфейс, который будет реализовывать внутренний класс. Тогда класс останется приватным, а в качестве типа ссылок можно будет использовать интерфейс.

```
public interface D {}

public class A {
    private class B implements D {
    }
}

public class C {
    D d; 
}
```

Это довольно распространенная практика в коде самой JDK.